# Alternative for deprecated AES_ige_encrypt() API in openssl

Tags: c++, c, encryption, openssl, aes

While upgrading from OpenSSL version 1.0.0 to 1.1.1x there was a warning that the API `AES_ige_encrypt()` is deprecated which is used for the encryption and decryption using AES_ige.
Even though the source comments says the function is deprecated it not mentioning anything about any alternatives for this API.
Searching the net didn't gave any useful information regarding this.
It will be very helpful if anyone can suggest the OpenSSL API that will provide the same functionality as `AES_ige_encrypt()` API.

Comment: _"...These undocumented functions ... has a known bug...."_: source: https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-commits/2019-April/022801.html  So not a public API and bugged.

Comment: My understanding is that not only the implementation (i.e. `AES_ige_encrypt()`) but IGE itself (i.e. the block cipher mode as such, [block diagram](https://nourbakhsh.ir/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/jakobsen-master-thesis-telegram.pdf), p. 11) is deprecated in OpenSSL. Then it is rather unlikely to find anything with the _same_ functionality that is _not_ deprecated in OpenSSL. But this is only a guess. You might find [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43842) and [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9515) interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the correct version of OpenSSL? That function is deprecated in the master branch (i.e. what will become OpenSSL 3.0), but is not yet deprecated in 1.1.1.

Anyway, you should not be using these modes. As per the CHANGES entry:

> *) The functions AES_ige_encrypt() and AES_bi_ige_encrypt() have
>   been
>        deprecated. These undocumented functions were never integrated into the EVP
>        layer and implement the AES Infinite Garble Extension (IGE) mode and AES
>        Bi-directional IGE mode. These modes were never formally standardised and
>        usage of these functions is believed to be very small. In particular
>        AES_bi_ige_encrypt() has a known bug. It accepts 2 AES keys, but only one
>        is ever used. The security implications are believed to be minimal, but
>        this issue was never fixed for backwards compatibility reasons. New code
>        should not use these modes.
>        [Matt Caswell]

As per my comment on the end - new code should not use these modes. If you are using them, then the alternative is to look for an alternative mode that meets your requirement and use the EVP functions to use that mode.

Comment: Or to grab the current code and fix the Bi-IGE bug for yourself, of course, then link against OpenSSL for the block cipher. Or re-implement Bi-IGE according to spec. But I'll be danged if I'm going to create a competing answer against Matt :)